# Invalid Bot Token, discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, environment-variables

I'm new to discord.js and I have no clue why I'm getting this error:

**Uncaught Error [TOKEN_INVALID]: An invalid token was provided.**

my bot.js file

```
    const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
    const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });
    
    client.on('ready', () => {
        console.log(`Successfully Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
    });
    
    client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

.env file

```
TOKEN='my Bot token here'
```

*I'm 100% sure* that my bot token is correct/valid, I have also tried revoking it and copy-pasting the new token several times, but I still get the same error... I have searched up nearly everywhere on the net and I still haven't found a solution to my problem.

package.json file

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^13.6.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to log the value of `process.env.TOKEN`?

Comment: Can you show your folder structure?

Comment: Folder structure, **Bot >** .env  bot.js **Node_Modules >**  Basic folders/files     Package-lock.json package.json

Answer (score -1):

Did you initialize the env to be used in your file?

You will have to use `dotenv` package.

Put `require('dotenv').config()` at the top of your file and you would be good to go

Comment: I have used `dotenv package` and tried `require('dotenv').config()`, but I'm still getting the same error...

Comment: Could you please show the value of `console.log(process.env.TOKEN)`